# Must be of order 5 and not 4

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

Let $f(x) = \sin x$.

Why can we say that the Taylor polynomial $p_3 (x)$ of degree $3$ gives an approximation of order 5 of $f(x)$? As I compute it, the error is rather of order 4.

Comment: The Taylor expansion of $\sin x$ has only odd powers of $x$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Can you explain in a more general way? I took this example, but I think the principal of order in a taylor polynomial is a bit misunderstood for me.

Comment: Or, as I would put it, the Taylor polynomial for $\sin$ of degree 4 is the same function as the Taylor polynomial of degree 3.

Comment: I was merely saying that $\sin x=x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\dfrac{x^5}{5!}\cdots$